# Unable to change button bound during its translation android

Tags: java, android

In my app I'm translating the button position when the listview is scrolling by like the code below

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount, int pagePosition) {
    int scrollY = getScrollY(view);
    ViewHelper.setTranslationY(profileButton, Math.max(-scrollY, mMinTranslation));
}
```

But I'm having a problem. It's not changing the bound position it is staying the position before it was the scroll.

Comment: What value are you getting in Math.max(-scrollY, mMinTranslation)?

Comment: Scrolling Up:
Trans﹕ -3
Trans﹕ -7
Trans﹕ -10
Trans﹕ -13
Scrolling Down:
Trans: -13
Trans﹕ -8
Trans﹕ -4
Trans﹕ 0